# SQL query split and correspond to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Table_A
name1
create_date

Table_B
name2
keep_time
```

`name1` is something like xxxxxx-yyy and `name2` is like xxxxxxx.  `name2` is exactly the first part of the `name1` separated by '-'.

I would like to get all the rows in `Table_A`, whose `keep_time` is less than (now - `create_date`).

As you understand, the problem is **how I can split the `name1` by '-' character** and get the first part and get the `keep_time` from `Table_B` by corresponding `name2`.

I need to write SQL in MySQL for such query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your requirements correctly:

```
SELECT a.* FROM table_A a
  LEFT JOIN table_B b on b.name2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.name1, '-', 1)
  WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), a.create_date) < b.keep_time
```

**EDIT** : DateDiff.

Comment: THanks it works great! But NOW() - a.create_date returns timestamp like 188006881.0000 but b.keep_time is an integer. How can I get the day count from the time stamp ?

Comment: Updated to use datediff, sorry.